# Composition of standard matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I understand that first of all you can do either Ta or Tb first because they both take elements in the domain of R to a codomain of R. Furthermore, I know that for A and B to commute, AB=BA. But I'm not sure how to write our the proof of this. Do I start by showing that Tb o Ta=Tba? I would then need to show that Ta o Tb is the same thing, but thats where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated, thanks.